# I told a small lie to prevent trouble after swearing to God I would tell the truth; is it a sin and what do I do?

Tags: oaths

Today my friends asked me if I could say "I swear in God I will say the truth" so said that. Then they asked me a question.  However, if I answered this question a lot of my friends will be in trouble, so I answered the question except a small part, which was a lie to prevent problems. I need to know if I have done a sin and if so, what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

**1**. If you are forced to take an oath, your oath is **not** in order.

**2**. Oath taken for performing Haram (Forbidden) and even Makruh (Non-recommended) acts is **not** in order.

**3**. Oath taken for abandoning Wahjib (Obligatory) and Mustahab (Recommended) acts is **not** in order.

**4**. Oath taken for performing normal acts whose performance **is not deemed to be better** in the estimation of people, will **not** be in order.

**5**. Oath taken for abandoning normal acts whose abandonment **is not considered to be better** in the view of people, will **not** be in order.

**6**. If you break an oath intentionally, you are obliged to give **Kaffarah** which is liberating a servant **or** feeding fully ten indigent persons **or** providing them with clothes.

**7**. If you cannot afford to carry out these three tasks, you have to fast for three consecutive days.

Comment: Plz feel free 2 provide some ref.s 4 ur ans.